# Proper Memory Management for this line? (Cocos2D)

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am getting the following line as a leak in Xcode:

```
someSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:(NSString*)obj];
```

I know that I do alloc it there but I thought Cocos2D handled all of the memory management. Anyway how should I properly handle that line in order for there to not be a leak?

Should I simply use autorelease or is there more to it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you were using ARC, this code would be a-OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually, it is more preferable to use static constructors that return autoreleased objects. For your case it will be

```
[CCSprite spriteWithFile:(NSString*)obj];
```

it will be retained when you add it to any parent

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2D does not handle memory for you. However, I think you can use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to get rid of having to handle memory yourself. You then have use Cocos2d as a static library since cocos2d does not support ARC.

If you want to solve your problem without ARC just insert a autorelease. If it is a instance variable, release it in your dealloc method instead.

Comment: I first also thought that Cocos2d handled memory for me, but it does not. It does however release all children (layers, sprites) that are added to the scene. And since most objects often are some kind of child, you often do not need to care for memory.

Comment: To enable ARC in a cocos2d project follow these instructions: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/
Or simply use Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) which has ARC enabled in all projects.